# How to use React.js from another .js file using CDN link like normal JavaScript/Vue.js?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to import React.js codes from from a .js file and use it in my index.html with react cdn imports. I needed to to very small task so I didn't wanted to use "create react app".

Is there any possible way to use React.js just like we can use jQuery/Vue.js using only cdn imports and importing them from a separate .js file?

What if I wanted to use react.js in an existing project along side another javaScript framework, without using create-react-app as it has its own project structure.

```js
//my_react.js:

class Greeting extends React.Component {

            state={

                name: 'Deutschland'
            }
     
            render() {

                return (<h1>Hello {this.state.name}</h1>);
            }
        }
     
ReactDOM.render(<Greeting />, document.getElementById('root') );
```

```html
//index.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Title</title>
      <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
      <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js">          </script>
      
      <script src="js/my_react.js"></script>
 </head>
 
    <body>
 
        <div id="root"></div>
   
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Browsers do not understand JSX format used by React for mixing HTML with JavaScript. You will need to transform JSX code to JS using `babel` before it can be included directly. Or you will need to write React code without using JSX. Continue reading for that.

The apparent capability of freely using html within JavaScript programs doesn't actually exist in any of the browsers. For most people, this mixed code with JS and HTML goes through a transformation and the result is pure JS code which can be run in any browser. Go through the React getting started guide to see how to achieve this https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html.

The transformation, for example, of the following snippet would happen in this manner:

```
    render() {
        return <div />;
    }
```

will get converted by babel to:

```
    render() {
        return React.createElement('div', {});
    }
```

The second snippet is something that browsers can understand and execute. You can obviously write the code directly in second format, and in that case no build process would be required.

React does (officially) support usage without JSX, see more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html. Be warned though, the React components written in this manner tend to be a bit verbose. Use this option only if you absolutely cannot have a build system.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. If I use the babel from the cdn sholdn't it work ? I included babel cdn in the index.html above but still it is not working.

Comment: Babel is designed to work with NodeJS environment. There is separate standalone package that does work in browsers. Check the documentation here: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html. After including it, you'd also need to include `type="text/jsx"` attribute on your script tag which loads jsx.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I actually did include type="text/jsx" .With it I need to run the react code from the same index.html file inside <script  type="text/jsx></script> but I was asking what if my code is too big and I want to write it in a separate .js file and in the index.html use   <script src="js/my_react.js"></script> to import it  and babel and react's cdn links to run it.